# Making shortcut in favourites to program extracted somewhere in filesystem from tar.gz

Tags: shortcuts, favorites

I have extracted some program in the downloads (blender) should probably move it somewhere else but anyway how do i make shortcut in favourites or all applications to such downloaded software?

I know there aren't "exe" files in linux but theres some runnable file inside extracted folder and its tedious to open Downloads or any other directory every time i want to run it

Comment: I'm confused why you are manually downloading Blender instead of using Ubuntu Software or Apt. Blender has been in the Ubuntu repositories for many years. The short answer is that you need to look up how to create and properly use a .desktop file. Software in the Ubuntu repositories already has the .desktop file.

Comment: ...duplicate:https://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop

Comment: @user535733 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204567/no-optix-tab-in-preferences-system-cycles-render-devices                                                                                       So yeah     "Don't use repositories, use the versions from blender.org. Repositories are created by third parties and may or may not be up to date or might be missing libraries."

Comment: You have a tradeoff: The Debian volunteers who package Blender do a great job integrating the application into the Desktop (the problem you are having). However, @susu is also correct -- that means you must live with decisions that those packagers make. There is no "right" answer - it's your choice between option A and option B.

Comment: @user535733 so yeah apparently they dont